# how to use conditional debug with lldb debugger in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, lldb

I am using lldb to debug c program in vscode, I want to conditionally debug a value which type is `const char`, but it didn't stop as I want.

I use `strcmp(xxx, "xxx") == 0` as condition expression, but not as my expect, the breakpoint just stop at the first time

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause for this is that your breakpoint condition didn't compile or run successfully.  If you were to do this in command line lldb it would have printed an error to that effect, but oftentimes GUI's won't surface this error...

When I add your condition to a breakpoint on macOS, when I hit the breakpoint I see:

```
error: stopped due to an error evaluating condition of breakpoint 2.1: "strcmp(xxx, "xxx") == 0"
Couldn't parse conditional expression:
error: <user expression 1>:1:1: 'strcmp' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type
strcmp(xxx, "xxx") == 0
```

If there's a way to run expressions in VSCode, then you can diagnose this by setting your breakpoint unconditionally, run to the breakpoint then run  your condition expression by hand and when you get something that works, add that as the condition.

In my case the failure is because lldb doesn't have debug information for strcmp, so you have to tell lldb by casting the result type:

```
(int) strcmp(xxx, "xxx") == 0
```

That's probably your issue as well.  In general, function signatures are only recorded in debug info for the module the implements the function.  If compilers didn't work this way debug information would quickly get unmanageably big.  Since you don't have debug information for the system C library, you won't have signature information for this function, so you'll have to cast it to its return type by hand.

Comment: Note, on macOS platforms, you can use the fact that the SDK is in the form of "clang modules" to reconstruct signatures from a module in the SDK headers by running the command `expr -l objc -- @import <ModuleName>`.  All the standard C library headers are in a module called Darwin.  You have to run this command after the process is launched but before you try to run an expression using the function.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. I have an answer, but not necessarily a thorough explanation.

TL;DR: try `xxx == "xxx"`, and make sure you aren't using any referencing / dereferencing operators. Also make sure to fully stop and start the debugger between changes to the breakpoint expression, as changes don't necessarily seem to take effect on a restart.

There appear to be two distinct types of expressions used in the LLDB debug console.

- If you type `p <expr>`, the expression in question will be C-style. This accepts standard pointer syntax, strcmp, and the kind of thing you would use in gdb.
- If you type `? <expr>`, the expression in question will not be C-style. I have a hunch this has something to do with LLDB's Python scripting.

The expressions used when setting a conditional breakpoint in VSCode are the second variant.

Syntax that didn't work for me

- `(int)strcmp(x, "string") == 0` (from Jim Ingham's answer)
- `val -> name == "3"`
- `x == 2 || y == 3`

Syntax that did work for me

- `x == "string"`
- `val.name == "3"`
- `x == 2 or x == 3`

I have not yet found the relevant documentation that explains this.